# Is it possible to create child window in opengl parent?

Tags: c++, windows, winforms, winapi, opengl

In my opengl project, i need to create some children of opengl window to get some UserInterface to the user and opengl to make some graphic in my program, and actually i have been successfully to make it all.. but the problem is: where we are going to move or resize the child window, my opengl background is getting fall appart yet when resizing and moving are done, my opengl background back to normal.

if it possible, could you explain me step by step to do it?
what should i do to solve this case?

Comment: create child window in parent window that contain opengl.. just like usually parent window and child window but in parent window is contain opengl. and the issue is: when i'm trying to move or resize the child  window seems the background of parent looks blur

Comment: So a window in a window? example?

Comment: You really need to show a little bit of code to demonstrate your situation better. OpenGL contexts are tied to windows "Device Contexts" (which are actually not much more than rectangular regions of an `HWND`). So provided the proper pixel format, you can easily change which DC a WGL context is associated with to implement something like drawing into child windows.